# MATLAB GUI - How do I remove the CreateFcn callback in my code?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm currently learning MATLAB's GUIDE gui programming. I notice that when I place some objects in a figure, a corresponding 'CreateFcn' callback function is creating in the associated .m file. MATLAB's comments state that this function is executed when the object is created (I would consider this a constructor for the object).

However, I've noticed that not all objects seem to have this 'CreateFcn' constructor. Static text objects do not appear to have this callback function. And as of currently, it seems like this function just makes the code more difficult to read. Thus I'm curious if I can delete.

By deleting it, I tend to get an error in my code stating that the function can't be found. So my question: is it possible to delete the 'CreateFcn' method to declutter my code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely it is possible.

Double-click the object to open up the inspector window, locate the "CreateFcn" property and set its value to an empty string. Then go to the .m file and remove the code of CreateFcn. This way MATLAB wouldn't complain about the missing CreateFcn anymore.

CreateFcn is not really a constructor per se, since it happens after all properties of the object are already set. It is more like an optional post-constructor event that gives user an opportunity to further customize the object's initial behavior dynamically. For example, you can customize the object's color at creation depending on the background color on which the object appears. For most control objects, the default behavior is probably already good enough for you. So you can safely remove those CreateFcns until you find a good excuse to use one.

Answer (score 0):

1) Goto the View --> Property Inspector
2) expand the Creation and deletion control, remove the text from CreateFcn and DeleteFcn 3) close the property inspector save the respective GUI (Don't forget to save)
4) remove the callbacks in m-script.